# Some integers related to the Hilbert scheme of points in the plane.

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, moduli-space

This question is related to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4157269/can-we-factor-this-quotient-ring/4157872) posed on this site.

Let me recall the construction: Let $A:=k[x,y]/I$ with $k$ the complex numbers (or any algebraically closed field) and $\dim_k(A)< \infty$. It follows $A$ is artinian and hence there is an isomorphism

$$\phi:A \cong A_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus A_d$$

where $A_i$ is an artinian local ring for every $i$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_i$. Since $\dim_k(A_i)< \infty$ it follows $\mathfrak{m}_i^{l_i}=0$ for some integer $l_i \geq 1$.

Let $\mathfrak{p}_i:=A_1\oplus \cdots \oplus \mathfrak{m}_i \oplus \cdots \oplus A_d$. It follows $A/\mathfrak{p}_i \cong A_i/\mathfrak{m}_i\cong k$ and $A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{l_i} \cong A_i$. It follows

$$\mathfrak{p}_1^{l_1}\cdots \mathfrak{p}_d^{l_d} =0.$$

By the chinese remainder theorem there is an isomorphism

$$A \cong A/(0) \cong A/\mathfrak{p}_1^{l_1}\cdots \mathfrak{p}_d^{l_d} \cong A_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus A_d$$

and since $k$ is algebraically closed it follows $\mathfrak{p}_i \cong(x-a_i,y-b_i)$ for complex numbers $(a_i,b_i)\in k^2$.

Let us lift the ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i$ to ideals $\mathfrak{q}_i \subseteq B:=k[x,y]$ with $B/\mathfrak{q}_i \cong A/\mathfrak{p}_i \cong k$. It follows the ideals $\mathfrak{q}_i \subseteq B$ are maximal ideals with

$$\mathfrak{q}_1^{l_1}\cdots \mathfrak{q}_d^{l_d} \subseteq I \subseteq \mathfrak{q}_i$$

for all $i=1,\ldots,d$.

Let us assume there is an equality of ideals

$$I:=(x-a_1,y-b_1)^{l_1}\cdots (x-a_d,y-b_d)^{l_d}$$

in $k[x,y]$, where $l_1,...,l_d$ is a set of integers $\geq 1$ satisfying a certain condition (see $C_1$ below).

Hence if our aim is to study the Hilbert scheme, we want to parametrize all length $n$ ideals, in particular we want to study the set of products of maximal ideals

$$I:=\mathfrak{p}_1^{l_1}\cdots \mathfrak{p}_d^{l_d} \subseteq k[x,y]$$

with $1 \leq d \leq n$ and $l_i \geq 1$. We find the formula

$$\dim_k(k[x,y]/(x,y)^i)=\binom{i+1}{2}$$

hence if $I:=(x-a_1,y-b_1)^{l_1}\cdots (x-a_d,y-b_d)^{l_d}$

it follows

$$\dim_k(k[x,y]/I)= \sum_{j=1}^d \binom{l_j+1}{2}.$$

Note that $\dim_k(k[x,y]/(x-a,y-b)^l)=\dim_k(k[x,y]/(x,y)^l$ hence

$$\dim_k(A) = \sum_j \dim_k(k[x,y]/(x-a_j,y-b_j)^{l_j}=\sum_j \binom{l_j+1}{2}.$$

Hence when studying the Hilbert scheme we want to parametrize ideals $I=\mathfrak{p}_1^{l_1}\cdots \mathfrak{p}_d^{l_d}$ with $1 \leq d \leq n $ and

$$(C_1)\qquad\dim_k(k[x,y]/I)= \sum_{j=1}^d \binom{l_j+1}{2}=n.$$

**Question 1:** Given an integer $1 \leq d \leq n$ we seek a combinatorial formula for the number $D(l_1,..,l_d,n)$ of unordered tuples of integers $(l_1,...,l_d)$ with $l_i\geq 1$ and $\sum_j \binom{l_j+1}{2}=n$:

Let $S(l_1,..,l_d,n)$ be the following set:

$$S(l_1,..,l_d,n):=\{ (l_1,..,l_d)\text{ an unordered set of integers $l_i$}. l_i \geq 1, \sum_j \binom{l_j+1}{2}=n \}$$

By definition: $D(l_1,..,l_d,n)$ is the number of elements in $S(l_1,..,l_d,n)$.

Do you know such a formula or a reference to where this type of formula is studied? I ask for an explicit reference to a study of this problem and such formulas in the litterature. If you have seen these numbers appearing in the study of the $n!$-conjecture I ask for a reference.

**Note 1:** I'm "imprecise" when writing $D(l_1,..,l_d,n)$ - this reflects that the numbers arise when studying the ideals

$$\mathfrak{p}_1^{l_1}\cdots \mathfrak{p}_d^{l_d} \subseteq k[x,y]$$

with $\mathfrak{p}_i:=(x-a_i,y-b_i)$.

**Note 2:** We may generalize these numbers as follows: If $A:=k[x_1,..,x_n]$ is a polynomial ring in $n$ variables over $k$, we may want to "parametrize" the set of ideals $I \subseteq A$ with $dim_k(A/I)=k$ for some integer $k\geq 1$.
Let $\mathfrak{p}_i:=(x_1-a(i)_1,\ldots ,x_n-a(i)_n)$ with $a(i)_j \in k$
It follows similarly (if we choose $d$ coprime maximal ideals $\mathfrak{p}_1,..,\mathfrak{p}_d$) there is an equality

$$\dim_k(A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{l_i+1})=\binom{l_i+n}{n},$$

and if $I:=\mathfrak{p}_1^{l_1}\cdots \mathfrak{p}_d^{l_d+1}$

it follows

$$\dim_k(A/I)= \sum_j \binom{l_j+n}{n}.$$

Let $S(l_1,..,l_d,n,d,k)$ denote the set of unordered tuples $(l_1,..,l_d)$ with $l_i \geq 1$ and with

$$ \sum_j \binom{l_j+n}{n}=k.$$

Let $D(l_1,..,l_d,n,d,k)$ denote the set of elements in $S(l_1,..,l_d,n,d,k)$.
I'm asking a similar question for the numbers $D(l_1,..,l_d,n,d,k)$.

Again I'm using an "imprecise" notation to indicate that these numbers arise when parametrizing ideals.

**Question 2:** Given an arbitrary field $k$ and an arbitrary finitely generated $k$-algebra $A$ with a confinite ideal $I \subseteq A$ (this means $I$ is an ideal with $\dim_k(A/I)< \infty$). Are you able to give an "elementary" parametrization of all such ideals $I$ using methods similar to the ones introduced above?

Comment: Why is $A$ Artinian? This happens iff $A$ is zero-dimensional. In general your $A$ might be one- or two-dimensional without further assumptions.

Comment: Your statement $I=(x-a_1,y-b_1)^l_d\cdots$ is incorrect in general for your give $I$. Are you defining a new $I$? What if $I=(x^2,y^2)$?

Comment: @Mohan - $dim_k(A)< \infty$ is an assumption - I added this condition.

Comment: I'll ignore your motivating manipulations and just discuss the question at the end. What do you mean by "a combinatorial formula"? Do you want to enumerate them? Or some sort of explicit algorithmic construction? Obviously you're trying to work with something very similar to integer partitions, but where each row actually has $\binom{l_j+1}{2}$ cells instead of the usual $l_j$ cells. (I guess you could think of it as a little triangle, maybe using the $z$-axis.) While formulas and asymptotics are well-known, the best you're likely to get is a generating function.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson - the motivation is there for people with interest in the Hilbert scheme and moduli spaces. You say "while formulas and asymptotics are well known" - please give a precise explanation of this statement and a reference in a post.

Comment: @hm2020 I suppose my point is that your actual question is very unclear. Your post spends 90% of its length discussing motivation and 10% discussing what you're actually after, and consequently only does the latter vaguely. As for formulas and asymptotics, if you glance at the Wikipedia page on integer partitions you'll see the classical formulas are prominent: the partition function, the pentagonal number theorem recurrence, the Hardy--Ramanujan estimate. If this is all you were after, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson - If you know an explicit formula for the number $D(l_1,..,l_d,n)$ defined in the post - write this in a post as an answer. –

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Answer:** The following construction gives a relation with **Question 2** and the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT) via Noether nomalization lemma (NNL). Let $k$ be any field and let $A$ be any finitely generated $k$-algebra and $I \subseteq A$ a cofinite ideal. By Atiyah-Macdonald Thm 8.7 (AM) and the NNL, since $B:=A/I$ is Artinian there is a decomposition

$$B \cong B_1\oplus \cdots \oplus B_d$$

with $(B_i, \mathfrak{m}_i)$ an Artinian local ring for all $i$. Since $dim_k(B_i)< \infty$ it follows there is an integer $l_i \geq 2$ with $\mathfrak{m}_i^{l_i}=0$.
Let

$$\mathfrak{p}_i:=B_1\oplus \cdots \oplus \mathfrak{m}_i \oplus \cdots \oplus B_d \subseteq B,$$

and let

$J_i:=B_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus (0)\oplus \cdots \oplus B_d.$$

It follows $J_i \subseteq \mathfrak{p}_i$ and that $\mathfrak{p}_i$ is a maximal ideal. There is an euqlity $J_1\cdots J_d=(0)$. The ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i, \mathfrak{p}_j$ are coprime for $i \neq j$. Similar for $J_i,J_j$. Hence there is an equality

$$(0)=J_1\cdots J_d = J_1 \cap \cdots \cap J_d.$$

Let $p: A \rightarrow A/I$ and let $I_i:=p^{-1}(J_i)$. It follows

$$I:=p^{-1}((0))=p^{-1}(J_1\cdots J_d)=p^{-1}(J_1 \cap \cdots \cap J_d)=$$

$$p^{-1}(J_1) \cap \cdots \cap p^{-1}(J_d)=I_1\cap \cdots \cap I_d=I_1\cdots I_d.$$

This is because the ideals $I_i,I_j$ are coprime when $i\neq j$.

We may lift the maximal ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i$ to maximal ideals $\mathfrak{q}_i:=p^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}_i) \subseteq A$ and it follows the ideals $\mathfrak{q}_i, \mathfrak{q}_j$ are coprime when $i \neq j$.

Since there is ain inclusion $J_i \subseteq \mathfrak{p}_i$ it follow $I_i \subseteq \mathfrak{q}_i$. There is an integer $l_i$ with

$$J_i=\mathfrak{p}_{l_i+1} \subsetneq \mathfrak{p}_i^{l_i}$$

and it follows there are inclusions

$$\mathfrak{q}_i^{l_i+1} \subseteq I_i \subseteq \mathfrak{q}_i^{l_i}$$

**Lemma.** Given any cofinite ideal $I \subseteq A$, it follows there are maximal ideals $\mathfrak{q}_1,..,\mathfrak{q}_d$ and integers $l_1,..,l_d\geq 1$ and cofinite ideals $\mathfrak{q}_i^{l_i+1} \subseteq I_i \subseteq \mathfrak{q}_i^{l_i}$ with

$$I=I_1\cdots I_d.$$

**Proof:** The construction is given above **QED.**

**Note:** A product of powers of maximal ideals is cofinite, and by the Lemma we may study ideals "squeezed" between powers of maximal ideals

$$\mathfrak{m}^{l+1} \subseteq I \subseteq \mathfrak{m}^l$$

to obtain all cofininite ideals. We say such an ideal $I$ is an "$(\mathfrak{m},l)$-squeezed ideal". Note that if $A$ is a regular ring of dimension $d$ it follows $\mathfrak{m}^l/\mathfrak{m}^{l+1} \cong Sym^l(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)$ hence  we have good control on the vector space $\mathfrak{m}^l/\mathfrak{m}^{l+1}$ when $A$ is regular.

**Example:**  If $A:=k[x,y]$ with $k$ an algebraically closed field we get the following: Consider the set

$$\{(a_1,b_1,l_1),\ldots ,(a_d,b_d,l_d) \}\in Sym^d(k^2 \times \mathbb{Z})$$

with $(a_i,b_i,l_i)\in k^2 \times \mathbb{Z}, l_i\geq 1$ and $\sum_j \binom{l_j+1}{2}=n.$

Here $Sym^d(k^2 \times \mathbb{Z})$ is the "set theoretic symmetric product" of $k^2 \times \mathbb{Z}$. The symmetric group on d elements $S_d$ acts on $(k^2 \times \mathbb{Z})^d$ and $Sym^d(k^2\times \mathbb{Z}):=(k^2 \times \mathbb{Z})^d/S_d$ is the "quotient". Let

$$H^i:=Sym^i(k^2 \times \mathbb{Z})$$

and consider

$$H(n):=H^1\times H^2 \cdots \times H^n.$$

We get a construction of all cofinite ideals $I \subseteq A$ of length $n$ as a subset

$$"Hilb^n(k[x,y])" \subseteq H(n).$$

Note: $"Hilb^n(k[x,y])"$ is a set, not a scheme.

Answer (score 5):

> **Question:** Given an integer $1 \leq d \leq n$ we seek a combinatorial formula for the number $D(l_1,..,l_d)$ of unordered tuples of integers $(l_1,...,l_d)$ with $l_i\geq 1$ and $\sum_j \binom{l_j+1}{2}=n$.
> Do you know such a formula or a reference to where this type of formula is studied? I ask for an explicit reference to a study of this problem and such formulas in the litterature.

The notation $D(l_1, \ldots, l_d)$ makes little sense. Presumably you meant $D(n, d)$ or similar. (Edit: as I was writing this, you edited the question again. I won't try keeping up with a moving target.)

If you replaced $\binom{l_j+1}{2}$ with $l_j$, you would be asking for the number of [integer partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$ of length $d$. These are extremely classical objects with a large variety of enumerative and other formulas, which the Wikipedia page summarizes nicely. However, in the comments you ask for an "explicit formula" for $D(n, d)$. While this is very vague, there is no such formula for integer partitions, nothing you can write in some nice closed form anyway. There's no chance in my mind that your problem will have a more explicit solution.

Nonetheless, you can likely use standard generating function approaches to get useful information here. What exactly is useful to you is not clear at present, but here's one observation. Let $m_i$ denote the number of $l_j$ equal to $i$. The corresponding "exponential notation" is $\{l_1, \ldots, l_d\} = 1^{m_1} 2^{m_2} \cdots n^{m_n}$. In general you want $m_1 + \cdots + m_n = d$ and $m_1 \binom{1+1}{2} + m_2 \binom{2+1}{2} + \cdots + m_n \binom{n+1}{2} = n$. (Of course $m_n=0$ here, well for $n>1$; this was just convenient.) The key thing is that the $m_i$ are arbitrary non-negative integers. Using the geometric series and standard manipulations with generating functions gives

\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n,d=0}^\infty D(n, d) x^n y^d = \prod_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1 - yx^{\binom{i+1}{2}}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: "However, in the comments you ask for an "explicit formula" for D(n,d). While this is very vague..." - The question is simple: I'm seeking an explicit formula for the number $D(l_1,..,l_d,n)$ defined in the post.

Comment: @hm2020 I don't mean to be combative, and I'm sorry if I'm coming across that way. Your definition is circular: you use $(l_1, \ldots, l_d)$ as both parameters and variables on the left and right, respectively. The phrase "explicit formula" is extremely vague--there is no way around that. I've tried to tell you what sort of formulas exist for a very well-studied variant of your problem.

Comment: I'm not doing combinatorics and the question may seem elementary for an expert. Still I was hoping for a serious response and references.

Comment: @hm2020 If someone asked you for an explicit formula for $\int e^{-x^2}\,dx$, you'd probably say it can't be done, and if you were feeling generous you'd point them to the Gaussian integral Wikipedia page to note that something similar does have a nice formula. I've done the same here. You've gotten as serious a response as you're likely to get to your combinatorial question in its current form.

Comment: You have yourself studied combinatorics related to the $n!$-conjecture and the Hilbert scheme, and this type of comment and reference was what I was looking for: Have the numbers $D(l_1,..,l_d,n)$ appeared in this study?

Comment: This is why I included a discussion of the "Hilbert scheme" of points.

Comment: @hm2020 Well first, as I keep saying, $D(l_1, \ldots, l_d, n)$ does not make sense. You seem in part to be ignoring the substance of what I say in favor of continuing doggedly in the track you wish to pursue. That makes this interaction less helpful than it could be. If you were the one who downvoted my good-faith reply, I strongly encourage you to reconsider your approach to this whole thing. (For the record, I did not downvote your question.) If not, I still think some reflection about your approach is in order.

Comment: @hm2020 In any case, to address the substance of your most recent question, no, I don't actually know of your weighted partitions appearing in Hilbert scheme and related theory. The closest thing that comes to mind is Mark's discussion after Prop. 3.2.2, page 947 of his polygraphs paper, which gives partition-many "most special ideals". I won't respond further; best of luck to you now and in the future.

Comment: I'll look up the reference. Let us not "quarrel" on the notation - it is completely clear from the discussion prior to the question what type of number I am studying. As I said - I'm not an expert in combinatorics and this is why I ask this question.

Comment: For fixed $d$, the number $p_d(n)$ of partitions of $n$ into $d$ parts is not such an awful thing to analyze: it satisfies a linear recurrence with constant coefficients (i.e., its generating function is rational). Evidently the same is true for this quantity $p^t_d(n)$, the number of partitions of $n$ into $d$ triangular number parts. (EDIT: whoops now I'm not so sure about this last assertion, because for the fact about $p_d(n)$, we have to transpose and consider instead partitions into parts of size $\leq d$; I don't quite see how you could do the same with the triangular numbers...)

Comment: @SamHopkins - please write this with more details in a post.